# How Do I Compare Two Datasets element by element in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, compare, element

I've need to check the test results of 50 different students against an answer key in A,B,C,D multiple choice fashion.

I have a one-dimensional data set for the answer key, "answers" that I read in as 
`answers <- read.table("A1_Ans_only.txt", header = FALSE, sep = ",")`

[View(answers)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UagEC.png)

I have the data set "results" that contains all answers for all 50 students. I read it in as `results <- read.csv("Form A1_only.csv", header = FALSE)`

[View(results)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CeVFU.png)

So when I try something like `results==answers` or `evaluate(results,answers)' with evaluate being a function I wrote defined as 'evaluate <- function(x,y){x==y}' I get all sorts of errors like "not equal-length data frames" or not same level vectors when I subset each to be one dimensional.

Can someone help me evaluate each element of the results data frame to decide which questions each student got correct?

```
This is a small sample of results: 


structure(list(V1 = c(1L, 3L, 5L), V2 = c(NA, NA, NA), V3 = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 4L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), class = "factor"), V4 =     structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), class = "factor"), V5 = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 3L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), class = "factor"), V6 = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor"), V7 = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = c("A", "C", "D"), class = "factor"), V8 = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 2L), .Label = c("A", "B", "D"), class = "factor"), V9 = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = c("A", "C", "D"), class = "factor"), V10 = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 1L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("V1", 
"V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", "V6", "V7", "V8", "V9", "V10"), row.names = c(NA, 
3L), class = "data.frame")


This is the sample from answers: 

structure(list(V1 = structure(1L, .Label = "AAAAKEY", class = "factor"), 
V2 = NA, V3 = structure(1L, .Label = "C", class = "factor"), 
V4 = structure(1L, .Label = "A", class = "factor"), V5 = structure(1L, .Label = "C", class = "factor"), 
V6 = structure(1L, .Label = "A", class = "factor"), V7 = structure(1L, .Label = "A", class = "factor"), 
V8 = structure(1L, .Label = "B", class = "factor"), V9 = structure(1L, .Label = "A", class = "factor"), 
V10 = structure(1L, .Label = "B", class = "factor")), .Names = c("V1", 
"V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", "V6", "V7", "V8", "V9", "V10"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do a comparison after replicating the 'answers' to make the lengths equal

```
results==answers[col(results)]
#     V1 V2    V3   V4    V5   V6   V7    V8   V9   V10
#1 FALSE NA FALSE TRUE FALSE TRUE TRUE  TRUE TRUE  TRUE
#2 FALSE NA FALSE TRUE FALSE TRUE TRUE FALSE TRUE  TRUE
#3 FALSE NA FALSE TRUE  TRUE TRUE TRUE  TRUE TRUE FALSE
```

The NA in column V2 for 'answers' results in the NA output as any equality comparison with NA results in NA.  If we need it as FALSE, then either change the NA afterwards to FALSE or do a `&` with `!is.na(answers)[col(results)]`

Comment: So what I got from that was a really long print out with every observation returned as "FALSE"

What exactly is happening there?

Comment: @Mr.T It returns a vector.  What exactly is your expected output?  Here, the each column of 'answers' is replicated so as to get the same number of observations in each column of 'results' and then do the elementwise comparision between the two

Comment: I'm hoping for a way to show which answers from students are "TRUE" or "FALSE" but it showed that every single entry was "FALSE". This is not accurate. How do I work around that?

Comment: @Mr.T  Can you show a small reproducible example using `dput` and update your post as I can't copy from your image and test it

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know how to do that. I tried ' dput(results) '. What do I do with that? Sorry, this is my first semester in R.

Comment: @Mr.T  Just subset a small number of colums and rows, and use `dput(yoursubset)` in the console and copy and paste the output in your post for both answers and results

Comment: @Mr.T  Yes, it is perfect.  By comparing, I get some TRUE values.  Please check the updated answer

Comment: So I've been working on this, and I'm looking for a way to write the comparison of the answer key to each row into it's own vector. So a vector for student_1 and his number correct/incorrect, a vector for student_2 and her # correct/incorrect, etc. I have tried:
`comparison <- results==answers[col(results)]

for (i in 1:nrow(comparison)){

          student_[i] <- comparison[i,]

}`

obviously to no avail. What would you recommend?

Comment: @Mr.T  Could you post as a new question as it is not clear from the comments